# How to download azure audit log

Tags: azure, logging, splunk

Is there a way to download the audit log on subscription level as well as diagnostics of the virtual machine, virtual networks, storage accounts, etc. ?

Edit: for more context -- I'm thinking of a powershell script that will be run by Splunk. The script will download the audit log and diagnostics then save it to a directory which Splunk will monitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cloud_solution_architect/archive/2015/03/10/audit-logs-for-azure-events.aspx). Which is exactly what I'm looking for.

So now I just have to write the script then have splunk run it on schedule. 
Thanks guys!

Comment: link is broken, can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Direct way to download the diagnostics data in Azure, By default no data is stored, if you want to store you'll have to start storing the data in Azure storage, from where you can visualize the data by using a number of ways

1. Use Server Explorer in Visual studio to view your storage resources.
2. Use Azure storage explorer by neudesic
3. Use Azure Diagnostics Manager by Cerebrata - this tool lets you download the logs if you want to as well as visualize.
4. Latest - you can use power BI to visualize your audit logs as well - I think this is the coolest of them all.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics-storage/
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbi/archive/2015/09/30/monitor-azure-audit-logs-with-power-bi.aspx

Comment: I believe you are confusing diagnostics data with audit logs data. Your answer (the most part of it at least) is for diagnostics data which is very different than audit logs data.